# buttons and input fields are shown with X symbol in MS IE

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

I have an issue with MS Internet Explorer 11 ver 11.0.14 where most of buttons and input fields are shown with X symbol as in the below image:

[image]

I am using Windows 8.1 Any advise?

Comment: Can you list what version of Windows and IE you are running?

Comment: I have updated the post accordingly.